# How to publish a Vue 3 component library using yalc for local development?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, yalc

I am developing a custom Vue 3 component library called my-components-vue and I'm trying to publish it locally using yalc for testing purposes in another Vite + Vue app. I'm encountering issues with making the library available for import in the consuming application, though.

**Directory Structure**

- src

  - assets
  - components

    - Button

      - Button.vue
      - index.ts
  - App.vue
  - index.ts
  - main.ts

`src/index.ts` (intended to export all components):

```
import type { App as VueApp } from 'vue';
import * as components from '@/components/Button';

const componentsList = components?.default;

const MyComponents = {
  install(Vue: VueApp) {
    Object.keys(componentsList).forEach((name) => {
      Vue.component(name, componentsList[name as keyof typeof componentsList]);
    });
  }
};

export default MyComponents;
```

`package.json:`

```
{
  "name": "my-components-vue",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  ... (rest of package.json)
}
```

`vite.config.ts` as follows:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url';

import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
  server: {
    port: 3000
  }
});
```

Also, when I run pnpm build, I don't see any js files...

**Question:**

How can I correctly publish my Vue 3 component library using yalc so that I can use the Button component in other Vue applications? What steps am I missing or doing incorrectly?

Any help greatly apreciated!

Steps I've taken:

- I have built the library using pnpm build.
- I published the package locally using yalc publish.
- In my consuming Vue app, I used yalc add my-components-vue to add the library.

**Issue:**

After following these steps, I'm unable to import and use the Button component in my consuming application. I'm seeing the following error:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import MyComponents from 'my-components-vue'

import App from './App.vue'

import '@/assets/main.css'

createApp(App).use(MyComponents).mount('#app')
```

**Cannot find module '.yalc/my-components-vue' or its corresponding type declarations.**